# The least value of $a + b + c$ where $a,b,c$ are not perfect squares but their pairwise products are

Tags: elementary-number-theory, optimization

The positive integers $a$, $b$ and $c$ are all different. None of them is a square but all the products $ab$, $ac$ and $bc$ are squares. What is the least value that $a + b + c$ can take?

A $14$   B $28$   C $42$   D $56$   E $70$

Is it C $42$?  $27 + 3 + 12$

Comment: 2, 8, 18 works too

Comment: I think @fkraiem gave the smallest solution, for I think that the numbers must be of the form $pq_{1}^{2}$, $p$ and $pq_{2}^{2}$. The solution with $p=q_{1}=2$ and $q_{2}=3$ gives the smallest one.

Answer (score 2):

WLOG, say $a\lt b\lt c$.  Note that, for a minimum sum, $a, b,\text{ and } c$ would be of the form $n,n\cdot s_1,n\cdot s_2$, respectively, where $n$ is a non-square positive integer, and $s_1,s_2$ are squares.

To minimize the sum $n+n\cdot s_1+n\cdot s_2$, we minimize $n$ and then the two squares. The smallest non-square $n$ would be $2$, which means $s_1=4$ and $s_2 = 9$ are the smallest squares we can choose.

Thus:
$$a+b+c = 2+2\cdot4+2\cdot9$$

Comment: Didn't notice @IndrayudhRoy's comment above before typing this out.  I'll just leave this here, unless anyone complains. `;)`

Comment: I don't see why anyone would/should complain. +1 from me.